# Launcher sshfs mount disappears after terminal is closed

Tags: mount, automounting, sshfs, launcher

I want to make a launcher in my MATE desktop that executes script for sshfs mount:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshfs login@server:/ /media/user/MOUNT_FOLDER/
```

This script is called by my launcher:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=/usr/share/icons/mate/scalable/devices/drive-harddisk-ieee1394-symbolic.svg
Icon[cs]=/usr/share/icons/mate/scalable/devices/drive-harddisk-ieee1394-symbolic.svg
Name[cs]=MOUNT MOUNT_NAME
Name=MOUNT MOUNT_NAME
Exec=/home/USER/mount_scripts/mount_MOUNT_NAME.sh
```

After entering my password, the mounting is correctly established, but when the opened terminal is closed, the mount point disappears.

Because the terminal is closed right after the mount point is created, I make just for test purpose another script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshfs login@server:/ /media/user/MOUNT_FOLDER/
$SHELL
```

When I use this script the terminal remains open, but again right after I manually close it, the mounting point disappears.

If I manually open terminal window (not by the launcher) and run the original script, the mount point remains open even after closing the opened terminal. So using the script itself should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=some_icon.svg
Name=Mount SSHfs
Exec=nohup sshfs user@server:/remote_path /local_path
```